# PUT request in node.js using $http

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to make a PUT request to a SQL database through node.js using AngularJS. I keep getting a 400 bad request error. Not sure what's wrong with the request, since this format works using a straight $.ajax call. Any help would be appreciated

```
  vm.approveUser = function(user_id){
    console.log('in approveUser');
    console.log('user_id', user_id);
    $http({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: '/admin/approve',
      data: user_id
    }).then(function(){
      console.log('back from the /approve');
      vm.getRequests();
    }); //end .then function
  }; //end approveUser
```

Comment: where is this function, ctrl or service/factory?

Comment: This function is in my controller going to the routes file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simplifying the request and add a return statement. See if it resolves.

```js
vm.approve = function(user_id) {
  var url = '/admin/approve';
  return $http.put(url, user_id)
    .then(function(resp) {
      vm.getRequests();
    })
    .catch(function(error) {

    })
    .finally(function() {

    });
};
```